# Converting React Class Component to a React Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert a React Class Component but have failed after a day full of failed attempts.

The current class component looks like this:

```
class NeonCursor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { top: 0, left: 0 };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
  }

  handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      top: e.pageY,
      left: e.pageX,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/react/cursor.svg"
        width={30}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: this.state.top,
          left: this.state.left,
          pointerEvents: 'none',
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

My current attempt looks like this:

```
function NeonCursor(props) {
  
  const [top, setTop] = React.useState(top: 0);
  const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(left: 0);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor');
    
    return () => {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    }
  }); 
  
  return (
      <img
        src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/react/cursor.svg"
        width={30}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: setTop,
          left: setLeft,
          pointerEvents: 'none',
        }}
      />
    );
  
  function handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    setState({
      setTop: e.pageY,
      setLeft: e.pageX,
    });
  };
  
}
```

So far, I have done the following steps:

1. Rename the class component by using function() naming
2. Remove the class constructor
3. Replace the state in the constructor by using the useState hook
4. Pass the ComponentDidMount and ComponentWillUnmount methods to a React.useEffect hook via callbacks.
5. Replace all `this.` syntax from the code.
6. Convert the handleMouseMove method to a function.

However my code is not working and always get a "Script error." message.

What would be the proper approach to this conversion?

I have prepared codepens for:
Original code: https://codepen.io/aegisnull/pen/YzLaxQJ
My attempt: https://codepen.io/aegisnull/pen/xxjWLXp

Comment: Those codepens look the same to me. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you define the useState hook in wrong way.

```
const [top, setTop] = React.useState(top: 0);
const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(left: 0);
```

It should be :

```
const [top, setTop] = React.useState(0); // 0 is initial/default value of state called top
const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(0);
```

Second, your handler also have a mistake

```
function handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    setState({
      setTop: e.pageY,
      setLeft: e.pageX,
    });
};
```

react fc component is don't have `setState` that's why before react have a hooks it's called stateless component. And when you define your state `[top, setTop]`,`setTop` is function to update the value of `top`.
So your `handleMouseMove` should be:

```
function handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    setTop(e.pageY)
    setLeft(e.pageX)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issues were your use of state and the location of the handleMouseMove function and the handleMouseMove function declaration.

Your state variables are called top and left and these are what you refer to when using the value (as per the style tag in your image). You update these using their associated set function i.e. setTop for updating top or setLeft for updating left (as shown in the handleMouseMove function). Their initial value is defined in the brackets. Since these are meant to store an x or y coordinate they are both numeric types.

The handleMouseMove function needed to move above the return statement to remain in scope and the declaration fixed.

Try this

```
function NeonCursor(props) {

    const [top, setTop] = React.useState(0);
  const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(0);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.documentElement.classList.add('no-cursor');
    
    return () => {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove('no-cursor');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    }
  }); 

  const handleMouseMove = (e: any) => {
    console.log(e)
    setTop(e.pageY)
    setLeft(e.pageX)
  };
  
  return (
      <img
        src="https://code.s3.yandex.net/web-code/react/cursor.svg"
        alt="cursor"
        width={30}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: top,
          left: left,
          pointerEvents: 'none',
        }}
      />
    );
  
  
}

export default NeonCursor;
```